# How can I find whether my Linux version is updated one?

Tags: linux-mint, upgrade

I am using Linux mint  with windows 10 in dual boot. For sometime now,I have been away from Linux boot. How can I verify whether my Linux is the latest one?

Comment: btw, if you don't want to reboot just to check you can run your linux partition as a VM, e.g. with virtualbox.  see https://superuser.com/questions/392601/virtualbox-using-physical-partition-as-virtual-drive

Answer (score 3):

Run:

```
apt update; apt list --upgradable
```

as root.

This will

1. Refresh the package database.
2. List all packages that are candidates for upgrading.

If the list from `2)` is empty, you're up-to-date.
If there are packages listed, you should consider upgrading those packages.

Answer (score 2):

If you mean a full upgrade to a new version of Mint:

Try the `mintupgrade` tool.  If it's not already installed on your Mint system, you'll need to install it, `apt-get install mintupgrade`.

Then you can run `mintupgrade check` to see if any upgrades are available, and `mintupgrade upgrade` to perform the upgrade (if an upgrade is available).

---

Otherwise, if you just mean updating the packages in your current Mint version to the latest packages for that version, it can be updated like Ubuntu, with `apt-get update` to refresh the packages available from the repos, and `apt-get upgrade` to install any upgrades that are available.

Comment: IMO this is the best rounded answer. +1

Answer (score 2):

The update manager will show up in your desktop environments task bar near the bottom right.

[image]

This will tell you the updatable packages for your current distro version and if there is a new version of the distro available.

Answer (score 0):

You can check your kernel revision with `uname -r`. See your distro's release notes, etc to see if you are on the latest version.

If you're expecting to be on the tip of mainline you can check the git branch at kernel.org to see if you are up to date.